# Find all real number(s) $x$ satisfying the equation $\{(x +1)^3\}$ = $x^3$ , where $\{y\}$ denotes the fractional part of $y$

Tags: real-numbers, integers, decimal-expansion

Find all real number(s) $x$ satisfying the equation $\{(x +1)^3\}$ = $x^3$ , where  $\{y\}$ denotes the fractional part of $y$ , for example $\{3.1416\ldots\}=0.1416\ldots$.

I am trying all positive real numbers from $1,2,\dots$   but I didn't get any decimals.

Is there a smarter way to solve this problem? ...   Please advise.

Comment: Use `$\{ x\}$` for $\{ x\}$.

Comment: You're trying all positive real numbers? xD

Comment: To begn with, the left side is a number between $0$ and $1$ , so the right side must be the same. This tells you that all solutions must fall in the range $[0,1)$ at best, if there are any solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fractional part is always in $[0,1)$. So the domain of $g(x)=x^3$ you are looking for is such that $R_g\in[0,1)$, which happens to be $[0,1)$.

$y=\{(x+1)^3\}$ is basically $y=(x+1)^3$ chopped into appropriate pieces and translated down by some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ where $k=\lfloor(x+1)^3\rfloor$

So we solve
$$(x+1)^3-k=x^3$$
which gives
$$k=3x^2+3x+1$$

Since for $[0,1)$, $0\le(x+1)^3<8$, we check
$$3x^2+3x+1=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7$$
whose positive roots give the answers.

Comment: In fact the fractional part is always in $[0,1)$

Comment: @MPW ugh my bad! edited. thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

Hints:

- $0 \le \{y\} \lt 1$
- so any solution to $\{(x +1)^3\} = x^3$ has $0 \le x^3 \lt 1$ and thus $0 \le x \lt 1$
- so $1 \le x+1 \lt 2$ and $1 \le (x+1)^3 \lt 8$
- any solution has $(x+1)^3 = x^3 +n$ for $n \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$, which gives you seven quadratic equations to check
- for example, $x=0$ is a solution when $n=1$

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all you're checking only 'all' integers and not all reals which include also $1/2$ or $\pi$ for example. I will try to give you an outline of how I would approach it.

Second of all, note that the left-hand side is always between $0$ and $1$. So, what is implied about the range $x$ might be in?
Once, you determined that you should be splitting up the range of possible $x$ into smaller segments such that for each segment you can find a natural number $n$ such that
$$\{(x+1)^3\} = (x+1)^3 - n.$$
Hint: there are $7$ segments that you should consider. Then for each segment it boils down in solving
$$ (x+1)^3 - n = x^3.$$
This looks difficult at first sight but I guarantee it will simplify to a quadratic polynomial (which you can solve). Please don't forget that the solutions of this equation should still be in the range on which we consider solutions to be part of.

I hope this helps and if you have any questions about any of these steps, feel free to ask them.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ...   This really helped. ...

Comment: I get the following answers :

Comment: for n=0, x is imaginary,          for n=1 to 6, i get $x$ = $0$, ${\frac{\sqrt{21}-3} {6}}$, ${\frac{\sqrt{33}-3} {6}}$, ${\frac{\sqrt{5}-1} {2}}$, ${\frac{\sqrt{57}-3} {6}}$, ${\frac{\sqrt{69}-3} {6}}$ .

Comment: for n=7, x is a whole number,          for n=8 to 17, i get ${\frac{\sqrt{93}-3} {6}}$, ${\frac{\sqrt{105}-3} {6}}$, ${\frac{\sqrt{13}-1} {2}}$, ${\frac{\sqrt{129}-3} {6}}$, ${\frac{\sqrt{141}-3} {6}}$, ${\frac{\sqrt{17}-1} {2}}$ .

Comment: and the list goes on ...   are there only particular solutions to this problem?,   or unlimited solutions...   please advise @Stan Tendijck   ...   Thanks again.

Comment: Well, the only solutions to the problem are given in your first comment. In your second comment, you forgot that whenever $x$ is inside the range (which is $[0,1)$ btw), $(x+1)^3 < 8$. This implies that solutions to the equation cannot be used for $n \geq 8$. For $n=7$, you also don't get a solution of the equation (but I would call that coincidence) since then $x$ should be $1$ which is outside the range $[0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks...   yes, i realized that the range is $[0,1) , which I had not realized earlier...   thanks again.   :-)